# How to correct access Hadoop 3.2.1 with Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop

I installed Hadoop 3.2.1 on remote centos server in a pseudo-distributed mode and and has checked firewall config. I exposed the ports 9000 and 9800-9900。Local environment is windows and a not started hadoop，I must install it or the application will throw an Exception that can't find HADOOP_HOME it also confuse me.

**My maven dependencies as follows：**

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

**My test as follows:**

```java
    @Test
    public void testHDFSRepository() throws IOException {
        Configuration conf= new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://remoteip:9000");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\111.txt"), new Path("/demo/111.txt"));

    }
```

then it throws an Exception and upload a 0B file toHadoop

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /demo/111.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)
```

the nameNode logs as follows:

```
2020-02-18 19:41:09,526 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 1 (unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) All required storage types are unavailable:  unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}
2020-02-18 19:41:09,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on default port 9000, call Call#4 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from xx.xx.xx.xx:13049
java.io.IOException: File /demo/111.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)
```

on the other hand, **I can use `bin/hdfs dfs -put` on the remote server successfully**。

Look at the error info I only have one dataNode indeed, should I add some datanode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datanode process is not healthy

> 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.

You'll need to inspect its logs or the namenode UI to determine the issue

> I can use bin/hdfs dfs -put on the remote server successfully

Then download the CLI tools locally and configure it for the remote server